# How could I set up a GM/admin NO-REPLY Email account on AWS SES

Tags: email

I regiested my doamin on route53 and also enable the SES,

However, I don't how to set up a system email eg: admin@mycom.com to send system mails to user.

Because I couldn't use a non-verified email account to be a sender.

But I don't know how to create a new email account that might look like admin@xxx sys@xxx under my current domain and make it verified by SES.

[image: inline]
[image: inline]
[image: inline]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems that you don't have any MX records, which means that there is no email traffic for this domain. You have to find an email provider (like Google or Microsoft) or you have to install your own email server (maybe you can use an image from AWS Marketplace). After you have your email server/provider, you have to add MX records at Route53(SPF, DKIM and DMARC records are optional, but I recommend it).

On that email server/provider, you have to create mailboxes which will handle the bounces and other related actions and you have to register this also in AWS SES. It will work if you do these steps.

**Update:**
As far as I see, there are other registered emails that you are using. You have the option to set up the new domain on one of your current server, or use it just like an alias-domain.

Comment: MX records are only required for receiving mail.

Comment: Sure, but to confirm an email address you have to have a mailbox (or at least a forwarder or alias)

Comment: hi, but we don't have to receiving mail. we only need to send system mails to users. is there any easier way to do. I thought once I own a domain I can do that.

Comment: You are never going to have the opportunity to confirm an email address, without receiving once - AWS has a strict policy for that. We just give a try several times, but won't work. If you think about it, just because you have a domain, or you can edit the DNS settings it is not meant automatically that you are authorized to send emails from that domain. Without proper bounce handling (and postmaster@, abuse@ and other RFC compliant email addresses) the service will be denied soon or later by AWS.